# how to access django form field name in template

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a modelform that I would like to iterate through the form fields in the template but at the same time, when I encounter certain fields, to conditionally render extra html. Currently I am pulling the field name from `field.html_name` but I am not sure if that is the best way (it feels hackish somehow, like I should be using a `getattr()` filter or something...).

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">

    {{ field }}

    {% if field.html_name == "location" %}
      <!-- CUSTOM HTML HERE -->
    {% endif %}

</div>   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What does the custom html do?

Comment: It adds another div. Mostly this is because the field with the name "location" is a ForeignKey and the div contains an <a href=> which allows to modify the location objects.

Comment: I can't find the exact part of the code at the minute but its something that django admin does similarly to add an add button for foreign key objects when using the admin model forms, so it may be worth looking into where they do that...

Answer (score 25):

I have the same situation if I don't misunderstand your mean. My solution is `field.name`. Code sample:

```
{% if field.name == 'password' %}
   <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{% trans 'Enter your password' %}">
{% else %}
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="{% trans 'Enter your email address' %}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @cowbert I guess this should be accepted answer since it actually answers the question?

Comment: I don't see how this is an improvement to the OP

Comment: Yes, I was looking for field.name while printing fields through a loop

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you mean, but you can try this

```
{% for field in form %}
   {{ field }}
   {% if field.label == 'Location' %}
      <h1>Hi</h1>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Whereas, you would have set label in forms.py as

```
location = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'yourclass', 'placeholder': 'Enter your location',
               }), label=u'Location', max_length=100, required=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't help me, since it is exactly the same approach as setting/getting `field.html_name`

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a widget or creating your own custom widget? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/

E.g.: for adding just a css class or similiar to the existing input [use the `attrs` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
     ...
     location = forms.CharField(
          ...,
          widget=Input(attrs={'class': 'location', 'style': 'background: red'}),
     )
     ...
```

Or creating a complete custom widget (take a look at how [Input](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Widget.render) is implemented)

```
class LocationFieldWidget(Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return mark_safe('custom html')
```

and then the form can be rendered in the template simply by

```
 {{ form }}
```

Comment: better yet, use [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) and keep the presentation information in the template only